# Using clush i need to save every host in the file(newnodes) into particluar file(slaves)

Tags: linux, bash, apache-spark

Could any one help on this using `clush` I need to save every host in the file (newnodes) into particluar file (slaves)

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
allnewips=`sed '/^#/d' newnodes`
for host in $allnewips
do
   clush -a  "\'$host\' >> /opt/mapr/spark/spark-XX/conf/slaves"
done
```

Comment: Please update also with whatever you have tried and provide an example for sample input you provide and output you are expecting.